# Cannot find either column "a" or the user-defined function or aggregate "a.Quantity", or the name is ambiguous

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

```
USE [CompanyTest]
GO

SELECT 
    d.code, 
    SUM(a.ItemID - d.itemID) AS BalancePeriodId,
    -- NOTE PeriodID 0 for current need to add 1 for last year
    (SUM(a.Quantity (CASE WHEN b.TransactionTypeID = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) + 
       SUM(a.Quantity (CASE WHEN b.TransactionTypeID = 16 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END))) AS QuantitySold,
    (SUM(a.Quantity  (Case when b.TransactionTypeID =17 then 1 Else 0 end )) +
    SUM(a.Quantity  (Case when b.TransactionTypeID =18 then -1 Else 0 end ))) AS QuanitityPurchased,
    (SUM(a.issuevalue  (Case when b.TransactionTypeID =15 then 1 Else 0 end )) +
sum (a.issuevalue  (Case when b.TransactionTypeID =16 then -1 Else 0 end ))) AS SalesValueSold,
    (SUM(a.CostValue  (Case when b.TransactionTypeID =15 then 1 Else 0 end ))+
     SUM(a.CostValue  (Case when b.TransactionTypeID =16 then -1 Else 0 end ))) AS CostValueSold,
    (SUM(a.CostValue  (Case when b.TransactionTypeID =17 then 1 Else 0 end ))+
SUM(a.issuevalue  (Case when b.TransactionTypeID =18 then -1 Else 0 end ))) AS ValuePurchased
FROM 
    dbo.TransactionHistory a
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.TransactionType b ON a.TransactionTypeID = b.TransactionTypeID 
                          AND a.TransactionTypeID IN (15, 16, 17, 18)
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.TransactionGroup c ON b.TransactionGroupID = c.TransactionGroupID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.StockItem d ON a.ItemID = d.ItemID
WHERE 
    a.ItemID = d.ItemID 
    AND (a.TransactionDate = DATEADD (YEAR, -1, GETDATE())) 
    AND a.TransactionDate >'2018-03-31 00:00:00.000' 
GROUP BY
    d.Code
```

I created this script a month ago to extract data in a set format to be used in another script to reimported into another table.

It worked for me then perfectly but now I get the ambiguous error and I just cant see why! Nothing appears to have changed on the server. I did change localadmin but that's back to as was!

Comment: "It worked for me then perfectly"  How can it work?  Your syntax is not even right.  How can your script run?  What is `(SUM(a.CostValue  (Case ...)))`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you don't use random letters such as `a`, `b` and so on for column aliases.  Use table abbreviations, such a `TransactionType tt` and `TransactionHistory th`.

As written, your query will not run at all.  The normal cause of an ambiguous column error is that columns are not qualified.  But all are qualified.  On the other hand, this expression:

```
sum (a.Quantity  (Case when b.TransactionTypeID =15 then 1 Else 0 end ))
```

Simply is not valid.  Perhaps there should be a `*` between the expressions.

My guess is that in moving the code to ask the question, you qualified one or more column names that are not qualified in the original query.

Comment: I agree it would make it easyier to use table abbreviations I will do that.

Comment: The summing you mention is out of context. I have a further sum before outputing the value; (sum (a.Quantity  (Case when b.TransactionTypeID =15 then 1 Else 0 end ))+ 
 sum (a.Quantity  (Case when b.TransactionTypeID =16 then -1 Else 0 end )))as QuantitySold,